# Is there some JavaScript 3d-physycs engine with integration with STL?

Tags: javascript, simulation, physics, 3d-engine

I want to make emulation of models for 3d printing on JavaScript. Is there any engines in which possible to load STL models? Or convert STL to other format (3d Max, Inventor, etc.) and then load to JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should try three.js library (http://threejs.org/).
Especially http://threejs.org/editor/, which code is availble on github. It has methods for importing STL models.